# importing variables into another file - getting an error while running file1.py

Tags: python, file, variables, import, global

I want to import some variable from variable.py file in this file.
I would like to run this file and import variables from variable.py.
How do I solve the error for file1.py?
file1.py is all a declaration file, at some point file1.py will be imported into another file at some point. pycharm recognizes file1.py has an error at  line 4 where the variables are used.

file1.py

```py
# 
1) import variable
2)
3)    def someFunction():
4)        c = variable.a + variable.b
5)        print(c)

### End of the file1.py
```

variable.py

```py
# This is my "global variable" defined file.

    def init():
        global a 
        a = 3
        global b 
        b = 5

### End of the variable.py
```

Comment: Is there a question you want to ask? Perhaps you are getting an error and don't know what to do next. You should update your question with the text of this error.

Comment: getting an error in file1.py. Thanks @quamrana

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Those variables don't exist until you run `variables.init()`.

Comment: Also, you can't declare a variable as global and assign it a value all in one statement.  `global a` has to be a separate statement from `a = 3`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the variables in a function?  Why wouldn't you just have `a = 3` at global scope?

Comment: This variables will be used in different files. Thanks @JohnGordon

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: This is part of my work, it depends on many dependencies ... does not have a dependent environment. That's is the reason I cannot run the program.

Answer (score 0):

1. ## 1.try this syntax

   ```
   from variable import *
   # 2. Or try this:
   Use if __name__ == "__main__" to Control the Execution of Your Code.
   #then write the code.
   def someFunction():
           c = variable.a + variable.b
           print(c)
   ```

#Hope this will work.

Comment: please edit formatting of your answer and take a look at its preview before applying the edit.